# How to call a method on a Web Component (Custom Element)

Tags: angular, web-component

I ve a web component which i wanna consume (and i cannot change) :

i dispaly it like that :

```
<custom-element #mycustomElement id="customElement"></custom-element>
```

then , in the ts part , i want to call a specific method called "**action**"

i ve tried this :

```
 @ViewChild('mycustomElement ', { static: true })
 mycustomElement : ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> = {} as ElementRef;


 this.mycustomElement.nativeElement.action('someMethod' , {});  // this doesnt work
```

But i ve had this error :

> Property 'action' does not exist on Type HTMLInputElement

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: You need to set the type corectly. CustomElementComponent i think not htmlInputElement

Answer (score -1):

Set variable type to component and then call its function

```
@ViewChild('mycustomElement ', { static: true }) myCustomElement : MyCustomElement;

this.myCustomElement.someMethod();
```